# Shading is off and/or planes are flickering

Tags: lighting, artifacts

Blender 2.83.4 Cycles.

I have an obj model that was purchased and given to me to use as a backdrop.

I'm not sure why pieces of the pipes are black.
In the rendered viewport shading- which I understand to be the closest representation to the actual rendered image as Blender has possible.

[image]

I'm not sure how to tell if it's inverted normals or improper lighting set up.  There are no image texture applied to the material, it's just straight Principled into material output.

The viewport shading menu has "Scene lights and Scene World" checked.  It also does not change anything in my viewport when I uncheck them.  The world does have an image applied but even when I disengage that from the World Output node nothing changes. If it helps though, it's a white-ish light HDRI.

I have an emitter object that I've disabled in the "viewports" and "render" areas of it's filters.  I also have two area lights that I've done the same to, so I believe I have switched off all of the lights that I've created other than the world settings.

There are also a few artifacts (I think I'm using that word correctly) in the walls; ie: a few planes are shaded slightly different as this one in this image is:

[image: Examples]

I am unclear despite my searching on how to fix this.  I have tried the merge by distance technique, decimate geometry, and also adding subdivisions.

Here is a link to download the project: https://we.tl/t-zsRWoTdIRn

If needed, this is the link to the purchased obj:  https://free3d.com/3d-model/warehouse-modern-interior-5522.html

HDRi can be found here: https://stock.adobe.com/images/full-360-degree-equirectangular-panorama-hdri-of-modern-futuristic-white-building-interior-3d-render-illustration/326519034

If anyone has the time and energy to help me figure this out, I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: Are the "offending" planes separate objects, or just a part of the existing "wall" object? I ask because "flickering" sections are often the result of Z-fighting (2 faces sharing identical "depth"). The rendering engine can't decide  which one to place in "front" at any given moment, so it's always switching back and forth. Your "merge by distance" idea might have been on the right track, but will not work if they are separate objects.

Comment: No the wall is all one object as are the pipes.